# Derivations of the free operad generated by a polynomial functor

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, monoidal-categories, operads

The following section in [Kontsevich' and Soibelman's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0001151.pdf) I don't understand:

> Let $F$ be a polynomial functor [this is the author's terminology for analytic functor as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797554/operads-and-kontsevich-polynomial-functors)], $P= Free_{\mathcal{OP}}(F)$ be the corresponding free operad. **Let $g_p$ be the Lie algebra (in the symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$) of derivations of the operad $P$.**

What is a derivation of the operad $P$? Is it a morphism of operads $d:P\rightarrow P$ such that $d(f\circ_i g)=f\circ_i d(g)+d(f)\circ_i g$ for all $f\in P(n), g\in P(m)$? References welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but there's a notion of operad derivation given in Definition 5 (page 10) of this reference: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.09581.pdf. There is also an older definition given on page 8 of this reference: https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9411208.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A derivation $d : P \to P$ is a sequence of $\Sigma_n$-equivariant maps $d : P(n) \to P(n)$ such that, for homogenous elements $a \in P(n)$, $b_1 \in P(r_1)$, ..., $b_n \in P(r_n)$, one has:
$$d\bigl(a(b_1, \dots, b_n)) = (d(a))(b_1, \dots, b_n) + \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{\epsilon_i} a(b_1, \dots, d(b_i), \dots, b_n),$$
where $\epsilon_i = |a| + |b_1| + \dots + |b_{i-1}|$.

This is defined e.g. in Section 6.3.1 of Loday-Vallette' book *Algebraic Operad*. Derivations on free operads are studied in Section 6.3.3, and in particular Proposition 6.3.6 states that a derivation $\mathrm{Free}(F) \to \mathrm{Free}(F)$ is the same thing as a map $F \to \mathrm{Free}(F)$.

This is equivalent to requiring that for homogenous $f,g$, one has:
$$d(f \circ_i g) = d(f) \circ_i g + (-1)^{|f|} f \circ_i d(g).$$

Note that derivations are rarely morphisms of operads. It follows from the axioms that if $u \in P(1)$ is the unit of the operad, then $d(u) = 0$. However, a morphism of operads has to satisfy $d(u) = u$. So, a derivation is a morphism of operads if and only if $u = 0$, in which case $P = 0$ is the zero operad.

Comment: Thanks, that helps! I've had a follow-up question based on your answer, but didn't want to ask a new question in the comments. Maybe you can help with [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808143/degree-p-derivation-of-an-operad-and-minimal-models) also.