# Decomposable differential of operads

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homological-algebra, operads, differential-graded-algebras

To my understanding, a degree $p$ derivation (for $p\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$) on a graded reduced (meaning $P(0)=0$) operad $P$ of vector spaces is given by a sequence of equivariant degree $p$ $k$-linear maps $\{\theta(n):P(n)\rightarrow P(n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ that satisfy a certain Leibniz identity. A differential on a graded reduced operad $P$ is a degree $+1$ derivation on $P$ that squares to zero.

So far so good. What irritates me is then the definition of a decomposable differential of a quasi-free operad.

Any (reduced) $\mathbb{S}$-module gives rise to the free (reduced) operad $F(E)$ on $E$. This free operad can explicitly described via equivalence classes of $E$-decorated trees. It has a natural grading given by the number of vertices appearing in the tree. With this weight grading, the weight $1$ component $F(E)^{(1)}$ can be identified with $E$ itself.

The differnetial $\partial$ of a quasi-free operad $(F(E),\partial)$ is now called *decomposable* if $$\partial(E)\subseteq \bigoplus_{l\geq 2}F(E)^{(l)}.$$

This sounds like an empty condition to me. By definition, the differential is given by a sequence of degree $+1$ linear maps, so we always have $$\partial(E)=\partial(F(E)^{(1)})\subseteq F(E)^{(2)}.$$

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that the differential is required to have degree +1, and not -1? In a context of dg-operads you will have people using homological and cohomological grading conventions. For instance, the Fresse paper "Koszul duality of operads and homology of partition posets'' uses degree -1 differentials, and section 3.1.7 contains this expression you have in the definition of ''decomposable'' as a nontrivial condition for something to hold.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. This is based on Chapter 8 of Markl's *Deformation Theory of Algebras and their Diagrams*.

Comment: I think here "weight" and "degree" do not mean the same thing.

Comment: @JHF What is a degree $p$ $k$-linear map $F(E)(n)\rightarrow F(E)(n)$ then? What does degree $p$ mean here?

Comment: Looking into the first few pages of the chapter you mentioned, it seems that Markl is discussing operads in graded vector spaces, so that $F(E)(n)$ is a graded vector space, and the degree of the linear map refers to this grading.

Comment: @JHF Yes, it is graded — but what apart from the weight grading can this grading  be? For a non-graded symmetric sequence $E$ the free operad on a symmetric sequence does not posess a natural grading apart from the weight grading, does it?

Comment: Markl starts with a symmetric sequence $E$ in graded vector spaces, i.e., each $E(m)$ has a grading.  This gets propagated into a grading on each $F(E)(n)$.

Comment: @JHF I see. So if the only non-trivial homogeneous components of $E$ are of degree $\geq 1$, then the differential is decomposable, right?

Comment: You may want to pick a specific symmetric sequence of graded vector spaces and figure out the degree and the weight of a nontrivial tree in $F(E)$ so you can see the difference. Decomposable is only about the weight, not the degree.

Comment: @JustinYoung Just to clarify definitions: The weight is the number of vertices of a tree. The degree is the sum of the degrees over the decorations of a tree. Here a tree is decorated by elements of the $E(n)$. The differential increases the degree by one. This does not mean that the number of vertices increases. Decomposable differential means precisely that any coboundary has number of vertices (weight) at least two. Correct? (Strictly speaking, when I say "tree", I mean "equivalence class of an $E$-decorated tree".)

Comment: Sounds better to me!