# Convergence of analytic functors?

Tags: category-theory, analytic-functions, functors, monads, categorification

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a symmetric monoidal cocomplete category. Let $F:\mathbb{P}^{op}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ be a functor, where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes the permutation category. Such a functor is sometimes called a symmetric sequence or a $\mathbb{S}$-module or a $\mathcal{C}$-species. For any such symmetric sequence $F$ we can consider its associated analytic functor (also called Schur functors)

$$\hat{F}[X]:= \coprod_{n\geq 0} F[n]\otimes_{S_n} X^{\otimes n}.$$
These appear naturally as the monads associated to an operad as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797554/operads-and-kontsevich-polynomial-functors). Why they are called analytic functors seems obvious: They look like categorifications (in an imprecise, intuitive sense) of formal power series. Now the ring of formal power series can be given a natural topology (several equivalent definitions exist, one is, for example, via the $(X)$-adic topology) and one can speak of convergence of formal power series.

This naturally raises the question:

- Is there a notion of convergence of analytic functors? Or does the analogy with analytic functions/formal power series end there?

In the realm of Goodwillies analytic $(\infty,1)$-functors, there seems to be a notion of [convergence of analytic functors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/analytic+%28%E2%88%9E%2C1%29-functor#convergence_of_the_goodwillietaylor_tower), but to my knowledge Goodwillie's analytic functors and those defined above are not related.

Comment: You can define a kind of $X$-adic topology here (where convergence means that the "coefficients" eventually stabilize) but I'm not aware of any uses for it.

Comment: If you wanted to make arguments involving "approximating" such a functor by e.g. its polynomial truncations, you don't need a topology to do that, you can just use filtered colimits.